# Angular - Injecting the parent controller into several child directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update my model based on user input. I have several (number varies between 1 to x) child directives marked here as A, B, and C that are just copies of the same entity. The controller is defined on MAIN page element (which has its own inputs) and then also injected into each of the child directives.

As of now, the problem is that all the child directives are sharing the same controller and model causing their inputs to override each other.

If I define the controller in each of child directives individually, then there is the problem of collecting all the data inside one controller.

TL;DR: I'm not sure how to update my model with MAIN input elements and the child directive (A, B, C) input elements while keeping the flexibility of adding/removing x number of the child directives.

I appreciate any articles or suggestions that you may have. I'm open to an alternative approach as well.

MAIN template:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as mainCntrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mainCntrl.formdata.page_title"></input>
    <div id="container">
        <child-directive cntrl="mainCntrl"></child-directive> /*gets added here dynamically*/
        <child-directive cntrl="mainCntrl"></child-directive>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="mainCntrl.submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

MAIN controller:

```
     .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
            this.formdata = {
                 page_title: "",
                 objects: {}
            };
            this.submit = function() {
                console.log(this.formdata);
            }

    })
```

Child directive definition:

```
    .directive("childDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                cntrl: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'templateurl',
        }
    })
```

Child directive Template:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="cntrl.formdata.objects.title"></input>
    <textare ng-model="cntrl.formdata.objects.description"></textarea>
</div>
```

And to visualize:

[image: visualization]

Comment: You say the child directives are added dynamically, what is the mechanism?  You don't appear to be using an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @csmithmaui that really has nothing to do with the problem. I have a button that appends "<child-directive cntrl="mainCntrl"></child-directive>" to the parent div

Comment: I'm not sure what you're end goal is here.  I think you're saying you don't want to share the controller across all children, but then why are you passing it as a variable to all children?

Comment: I was just wondering because if you used an `ng-repeat` I was thinking you might be able to use the $index somehow.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams, thats correct, I dont want to share it with the children and I know I shouldnt pass it into them. How do you suggest I should update my MAIN model with the children's fields? If you look at the MAIN controller, I'm console logging the formdata object on submit. My end goal is to have the children update formdata.objects where it contains the info from each of the children separately. formdata.objects[1].title, formdata.objects[2].title and so on...

Comment: I see.  How about having a separate child controller instance for the directives and then sharing the data using a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, just an idea:

**Change objects to an array.**

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        this.formdata = {
             page_title: "",
             objects: []
        };
        this.submit = function() {
            console.log(this.formdata);
        }

})
```

**Create a child controller that pushes it's model to the objects array:**

```
.directive("childDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            cntrl: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'templateurl',
        controller: ChildCntrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
})

ChildCntrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function ChildCntrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.model = {
        title: null,
        description: null
    };
    $scope.cntrl.formdata.objects.push(model);
}
```

**Use the model in you Child Directive template:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.model.title"></input>
    <textare ng-model="vm.model.description"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly the behavior i was looking for. Thanks!